# How do I customise date/time bindings using JAXWS and APT?

Tags: java, binding, jaxb, jax-ws, apt

Im using JAXWS 2.1.7, using some classes to run through JAXWS's 'apt' to generate the WSDL.  For dates, I use

```
@XmlSchemaType(name="time")  
private Date wakeupTime;
```

and this generates a schema with xs:time, but when this all comes out in XML, the value is something like

```
<wakeupTime>1901-01-01T01:00:00 +10</wakeupTime>
```

I want JUST the time portion to come!  I think I want to use a custom converter to say that xs:time + java.util.Date should be printed and parsed in such-and-sucha manner, but I cant see that I can pass a bindings file to the apt routine.  I can't (for historical & other reasons) use `XMLGregorianCalendar` - it has to be a `java.util.Date`.  How do I specify a custom binding for the apt tool in jaxb

Answer (score 8):

OK, found it!  Read this link: http://weblogs.java.net/blog/2005/04/22/xmladapter-jaxb-ri-ea
and use a javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter.  i.e.

```
public class TimeFromDateAdapter extends XmlAdapter<XMLGregorianCalendar, Date>
{
  public Date unmarshal(XMLGregorianCalendar value)
  {
    Calendar cal = value.toGregorianCalendar();
    Date d = cal.getTime();
    return d;
  }

  public XMLGregorianCalendar marshal(Date value)
  {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(value);
    try
    {
    XMLGregorianCalendar xmlcal =   DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendarTime(cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE), cal.get(Calendar.SECOND), 0);
    return xmlcal;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

and then :
@XmlSchemaType(name="time")
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(mypackage.TimeFromDateAdapter.class)
private Date wakeupTime;

and away you go.